# Upgrading Win 7 beta to final - will old MBR survive?

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I want to upgrade Win 7 beta to newly bought final version (Home Premium). I also have 'Boot from old windows' choice with XP SP3. The question is, is it safe to upgrade/install Win7? Will it recognize XP MBR saved by beta and preserve it for future use?

P.S. Also, the installation will be from W7 disk, as I cannot boot into W7 beta anymore (stuck in infinite "repairing" process).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your old MBR (assuming Windows 7 is installed on the primary partition) will probably not survive. But this is OK, since the Windows 7 installation process will search all drives to look for older windows versions to add to it's bootloader. Then it will write a new MBR (with the new W7 and old CP) to the disk.

Comment: If you just do an upgrade rather than a reinstall, it should use the old MBR.

Comment: @Justin can you do an upgrade from the beta to a full retail version? I'm not sure myself.

Comment: @ChrisF - It's the RC version that cannot be upgraded to the RTM version, not the Beta one.

Comment: @Isxek - I knew there was a restriction somewhere, thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, system installed. I had to wipe out Beta partition as system languages do not match, and still my "Boot previous system" option works nice.